# How to make virtual touch screen toggle stick/joy stick in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working on a home project about making a controllable floor tank. I am using my RPi 3B+ and a motor driver controller board to get motors moving. I have been using a tightvnc server to connect through the wifi with my phone, however, I plan on moving to an Ad-hoc network. Sure, I could type in a line of code for each direction I wish the motors to turn, but that's inconvenient and ineffective. I have seen people do this before, however, I am not experienced enough to produce this kind of code. I need a program, in which, when I run, opens a virtual touch screen toggle stick in python. Moving this up and down would also need to send those same(or very similar) lines of code. I will display the code I am currently using to run the motors. Thanks.

I have been trying googling and looking on GitHub for this source code, however, no luck so far.

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

def init(): #setup for the gpio pins being used
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
    gpio.setup(17, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(22, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(21, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(20, gpio.OUT)

def forward(tf):
    init()
    gpio.output(22, False) #Low
    gpio.output(17, True) #High
    gpio.output(21, False)
    gpio.output(20, True)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()

def reverse(tf):
    init()
    gpio.output(22, True) #High
    gpio.output(17, False) #Low
    gpio.output(21, True)
    gpio.output(20, False)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()

def alternate(tf):
    init()
    gpio.output(22, True) #Clockwise Motor 1
    gpio.output(17, False) #Counter-Clockwise Motor 1
    gpio.output(21, False) #Clockwise Motor 2
    gpio.output(20, True) #Counter-Clockwise Motor 2
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()

def RunPWM(tf):
    init()
    pwm_22 = gpio.PWM(22,100) #setting up PWM for gpio pin 22 & 21 out of 100%
    pwm_21 = gpio.PWM(21,100)

    pwm_22.start(20) #runs the gpio pins 22 & 21 at a pulse width of 20/100
    pwm_21.start(20)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()

print("forward")
forward(2)

print("reverse") 
reverse(2)

print("alternate")
alternate(2)

print("PWM")
RunPWM(2)
```

This code runs well and is a great way to test to make sure the code is running well and all hardware is in good shape and working. Unless I made a typo retyping this off of my RPi, this always runs flawlessly for testing, however, you cannot control a floor tank with this code using a touch screen toggle stick. If anyone has any ideas of about a different approach I could take, or if someone can make some code that fits this bill, it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Pygame which is pre-installed in full version or Raspbian has build-in library on handling [joystick](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html).

Comment: do you know how to call and import the library?

Comment: hcheung, without any other information, that doesn't help me much

Comment: Well, you can wait for someone to write the code for you, or read and learn. If you care to scroll down the link that I provided, there are sample code there.